# CSS update :after when input is checked

Tags: html, css, sass

Please note the HTML cannot be modified.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group newsletter">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input name="newsletter" type="checkbox" value="Sign me up for exclusive discounts and style advice by email, post and text" aria-invalid="false">Sign me up for exclusive discounts and style advice by email, post and text</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SASS:**

```
.form-group {
    input {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    label {
        &:after {
            float: left;
            display: block;
                content: "";
            width: 52px; height: 52px;
                margin-right: 35px;
            background: url('../img/checkbox-default.png') no-repeat;
        }
        input:checked ~ &:after { // This. Not sure how to make this work
            background: url('../img/checkbox-checked.png') no-repeat;
        }
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dfx78wob/

Comment: You might need te define the input type. like input[type=radio]:checked

Comment: Hey Robbin! It shouldn't matter, but I've done it anyways because desperate hehe.. no dice though: https://jsfiddle.net/dfx78wob/1/

Comment: `input:checked ~ &:after` there is no sibling **element** to input tag. So this won't work.

Comment: @Mr_Green I know the above would never work, but had to try something :(

Comment: @adamj With css only if you want to acheive that. The only solution is use `:after` on `input` element rather than on `label`. If you can manipulate the html then you should put `label` after the input element.

Comment: @user31782 Yes that's what I did made a mistake with my first effort though, now working.

Comment: Bring label and input element to same label and use the sibling selector

Comment: @MarkWilson No changing HTML apparently, anyway there is no need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no sibling element to input tag so using of `~` will not work. You either need to add a sibling element to input tag or add a class to `label` element. Since, you can't change the HTML the solution is possible only with JavaScript where you have to add a class to `label` element when input is checked.

```
input.addEventListener('change', function(){
    var type = this.checked? "add": "remove";
    this.parentElement.classList[type]('checked');
}
```

And in CSS:

```
label{
    &.checked::after{  /* instead of "input:checked ~ &:after" */
     /* checked styles here */
    }
}
```

BTW, it is always a better strategy to keep an empty element adjacent to input tag (*because input can't have pseudo elements*). So, you won't end up in situations like this :)

Comment: I was leaving that one as a last resort. I thought perhaps someone here might know of a trick or something along those lines to get this going. DAMMIT! haha

Answer (score 6):

This [*technically*](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has) will solve your problem...

```css
.form-group label:has(input:checked):after {
    background: url('../img/checkbox-checked.png') no-repeat;
}
```

... hopefully about 3 years from now.

Comment: Why do you have to play with my feelings like that :'(

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO:**

https://jsfiddle.net/dfx78wob/2/

You have used the `~` operator but label is the parent element in your markup. And there is no parent selector as of now in CSS.

So, I modified the html to make label a sibling of input and modified the style rules to use `+` instead of `~` as `+` will select the immediate next element while `~` will select sibling but not necessarily next.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group newsletter">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input name="newsletter" type="checkbox" value="Sign me up for exclusive discounts and style advice by email, post and text" aria-invalid="false" id="checkbox1">
        <label for="checkbox1">Sign me up for exclusive discounts and style advice by email, post and text</label>
    </div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
.form-group {
    input {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    label {
        &:after {
            float: left;
            display: block;
                content: "";
            width: 52px; height: 52px;
                margin-right: 35px;
            background: red;
        }
   }
  input:checked+label:after { // This. Not sure how to make this work
    background: green;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Mark! Appreciate your help, but the HTML is pre-generated by a plugin I use and I cannot modify it unless I use JS to do it, which isn't something I was gunning to do. If I could modify the HTML I honestly wouldn't be here, because it's a straightforward problem with a straightforward solution

Answer (score 0):

No way to do it unless you modify the HTML and this wasn't an option for me, so in the end I used JS as this was the only option for me:

```
$('<span class="check">').insertAfter( $('.checkbox.newsletter label input') );
```

---

Thanks @Sarcoma! Nice shot at the pseudo-element inside input. It just wasn't meant to be (damn you Firefox why have you forsaken me!).